Protect deep linking routes with go_router
I have in my application some routes that are only for premium users, and some routes shouldn't be accessed if the user isn't logged in, now the question is, how to prevent users from being able to access these routes when they are directed within a deep link?
Thanks.
I tried the redirecting method, to check my authprovider if the user != null only then access /nav screen for example, otherwise return null, but still with the deeplink test command, I can access any page
adb shell 'am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW \
    -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE \
    -d "https://my-domain/nav/subscribtion-screen"' \
    <my-package-name>

redirect method:
 redirect: (context, state) async {
      final token = await HiveBoxService().getAuthToken();
      if (token == null) {
        return RoutePaths.authScreen;
      }
      return null;
    },

